# Write data to NTAG213

Tags: ios, bluetooth, nfc

Hi in my iOS app I'm trying to use the [ACR1255U](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/403/acr1255u-j1-bluetooth%C2%AE-nfc-reader/), I want to write to a NTAG213 card some data,I found a way by using APDU command. I found a list of APDU command [here](http://techmeonline.com/most-used-smart-card-commands-apdu/), so the command to update binary for ACR1255U it's the follow:

```
FF D6 00 P1 Lc DATA (P1 --> starting block to update, Lc --> number of bytes)
```

so for example if I want to write A003, I generate the following NSString:

```
FF D6 00 04 04 41 30 30 33
```

but sometimes when I try to write it to a card it works perfectly and sometimes it fails, but I've no idea why... The command is correct and I'm using the SDK inserted in demo app that I download from [here](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/7333/ACSBT-EVK-iOS-Mac-0.02.zip).
Does anyone has an idea about why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work?
Thank you
It happen in the demo app and in my app

Comment: The command looks fine. Do you get an error code (e.g. `63 00`) in response when the command fails or do you get a success response (`90 00`) in both cases? If the command fails, what response do you get if you send the command `FF CA 00 00 00` (or `FF B0 00 04 10`) immediately after the failed write command?

Comment: In demo app I tried to send a command like my example (`FF D6 00 04 04 41 30 30 33`), when I transmit APDU it answer me with `63 00` (command fails). If I send `FF B0 00 04 10` it answer me with the follow: `01 02 03 04 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00`. I guess something goes wrong when I try to write an information to the card. I'm sure that I'm using a NTAG213 card (it's written on it). When I try to see the ATR it shows me the following code `3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 03 00 00 00 00 68`

Comment: Did you try to send the write command **immediately** followed by the read command when the first failed and the second succeeded? Or did you manually type and send one command after another (probably having a delay of several seconds in between the commands)?

Comment: I tried to send it manually so the card has time to set the data in the blocks. By the way my card has an NTAG213 chip inside and I found the data sheet here: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf and it says me that I've to use the command at page 32

Comment: The datasheet only tells you the low level commands of the tag. The reader performs abstraction of these commands based on the PC/SC specification (for memory cards). Thus you have to use the reader commands `FF B0 ...`, `FF D6 ...` to read/write NTAG chips.

Comment: Please try to send these commands **immediately** after each other. There really is no such thing as "time to set the data in the blocks". You can read immediately after the write operation. What I suspect (and what I'm trying to have you find out) is if the reader loses communication to the card during the write operation (e.g. because the tag is not properly placed on the reader or beacause the reader does not perform well in combination with that specific tag/tag antenna shape).

Comment: I tried your suggestion so I made a function in which I send the write command to the writer and after that I send the read command, if I try this it shows me empty response, because I'm thinking that the code is not set... The card ATR is the follow: `3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A`

Comment: An empty response with status word `90 00`?

Comment: No it answer with 63 00

Comment: Then I would say that this is a rather clear sign that the reader lost the connection to the tag. There is not much you can do about this, other than waiting until the reader detects the tag again (e.g. by reading the UID `FF CA 00 00 00` or the emulated ATR `FF CA 01 00 00`) and re-trying when the tag is detected again.